# Request Tracker - Changing Queue Color

Tags: perl, rt

I'd like to change the ticket table in RT to have a custom "Queue" color. I am using this guide as a reference:

http://requesttracker.wikia.com/wiki/ShowStatusInColor

... which works. The following code in a Callback will update all "Priority" fields to be red:

```
<%INIT>
      # Set the priority color.
      sub PriorityInColor {
        my $Ticket = shift;
        my $priority = $Ticket->Priority;
        my $colors = "#FF0000";
        $priority = "<div style=\"color: $colors;\">$priority</div>";
        return \"<b>$priority</b>";
      }

      $COLUMN_MAP->{Priority}->{value} = \&PriorityInColor;
</%INIT>

<%ARGS>
    $COLUMN_MAP => undef
</%ARGS>
```

Looks like this:

[image: Priority shows up red]

This also holds true for most other fields except the Queue. When applied to Queue, it has no result at all:

```
<%INIT>
      # Set the queue color.
      sub QueueInColor {
        my $Ticket = shift;
        my $queue = $Ticket->Queue;
        my $colors = "#FF0000";
        $queue = "<div style=\"color: $colors;\">$queue</div>";
        return \"<b>$queue</b>";
      }
      $COLUMN_MAP->{Queue}->{value} = \&QueueInColor;
</%INIT>

<%ARGS>
    $COLUMN_MAP => undef
</%ARGS>
```

I feel like I'm missing some additional arguments for Queue, but I can't for the life of me make sense of the structure if that's the case. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more trial and error, I found the issue! Queue references the internal number of the queues, QueueName references the actual string in the table. In addition, you have to call the name via "QueueObj" to get the Name attribute. Here's the working block:

```
<%INIT>
      # Set the queue color.
      sub QueueInColor {
        my $Ticket = shift;
        my $queue = $Ticket->QueueObj->Name;
        my $colors = "#FF0000";
        $queue = "<div style=\"color: $colors;\">$queue</div>";
        return \"<b>$queue</b>";
      }
      $COLUMN_MAP->{QueueName}->{value} = \&QueueInColor;
</%INIT>

<%ARGS>
        $COLUMN_MAP => undef
</%ARGS>
```

Comment: Good digging to sort that out. The other approach is to look at the source of the generated page, note the classes and ids, and do it all in CSS. You don't say which version you're running, but RT adds more classes and ids to the markup with each release to make this easier.